# How do I run a PHP script continuously on localhost?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, localhost

I have a script which crawls info using API. What I want is to run this script continuously to grab data and store it on my local machine. I configured machine as localhost and installed phpmyadmin and MySQL.

Comment: if youre using a nix you could set the script up as a cron job.

Comment: On Windows you could use a Scheduled Task, instead of a cronjob.

Answer (score 4):

You probably will want to run it from the [command line](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php). Put your code in some kind of loop to always keep it running, or schedule it to run as a cron job / scheduled task.

Comment: this is a windows machine and my scrypt is in loop so it will run for two three hours but after that internet explorer stops / if firefox then it crashes

Comment: you will also want to initialize the script on reboot. I have done this sort of thing for daemons on linux systems.

Comment: @mathew: for windows use the `start` command. To have it start at bootup you can modify the registry.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your main code, except for functions, classes, etc, in this:

```
while (true) {
```

and this:

```
  sleep(2);
}
```

Then run it from the command line, using:

```
$ php myscript.php
```

If using Windows, you manually have to add php to your PATH. I don't know Windows (using a Mac all my life) but I guess you can do this in My Machine's Properties. :)

Comment: I have added sleep function in the begining when I started this script for long time excecution. but what happens is number of data that it grabbing is less due to sleep function. so is there any other alternetive??

Comment: Setting sleep to a lower value, like 0.5, or removing it completely, resulting in your script performing a DDoS attack. :) but please be careful with too many requests as you may get kicked from using the API.

Comment: how do I put a path in command line?? my path is c:\\apache\wwww\

Answer (score 0):

Read about [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php), or modify `max_execution_time` value in your `php.ini` file  .

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a php loop, use a batch file loop. .

This gets around any set_time_limit , maximum memory etc problems. If php crashes, no problem, a new instance will be started immediately.

```
@echo off
:loop
php myScrapeScript.php
goto loop;
```